# Scrollbar above content

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

In the following code, I'm trying to build table like design with flexbox display model.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    background: grey;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
    border: 3px solid green;
}
.cell {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">1</div>
      <div class="cell">2</div>
      <div class="cell">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="overflow: auto;">
      <div class="cell">1</div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div style="height: 200px;">huge content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">1</div>
      <div class="cell">2</div>
      <div class="cell">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is, that in second row (with that "huge content") is scrollbar, and that scrollbar is taking space from my row cells and that's huge problem because my columns don't have the same width and it doesn't look like a table.

Things I can't use:

- my own implementation of scrollbars (performance is an issue).
- fixed widths of columns or `.container` (components height and width has to adapt).

[Real world usage of component](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6QwWVutfGaEZTl3bXBmUFF2UjA/edit?usp=sharing)

So, I need to make the scrollbar in the second row to be above that content and not to take that space.

Comment: you've hard coded overflow: auto into one of the divs, take that out and it'll be ok

Comment: Please avoid mixing inline and external css rules...

Comment: When I remove that style="overflow: auto;" I can't scroll with my content in second row.

Answer (score 49):

### 2023 update:

This has been removed from all browsers and is no longer a functional solution (see [compatibility chart](https://caniuse.com/css-overflow-overlay)).

---

#### Original answer:

I found, that exists `overflow: overlay` , which works as I want.

It renders the scrollbar, but doesn't take that space

See: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dk9m5/1/)

Comment: Note that this is a webkit only property. For IE10+/Edge you could use `-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;`. It does nearly the same thing, but the scrollbar does hide if the cursor is not at targeted element.

Comment: This is exactly what i have been searching for. Thank you!

Comment: In addition, if hiding the scrollbars is an option you're able to hide them completely using CSS, although like @JacobvanLingen mentions, I don't think IE/Edge have control over the scroll bar thumb etc like WebKit does

Comment: `overflow: overlay` was deprecated and is only supported in webkit and blink based browsers developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: This does not work now. Scrollbars will take place even if `overflow: overlay;` is set.

Comment: I have found difference when Safari v14.0.3 on iOS support "overlay" but Safari same version v14.0.3 on Mac OS does not support. Why Safari is different on Mac OS vs iOS when it has identical version? Also Safari on Mac show scroller behind radiuses of parent element while Safari on iOS does not. So this two thinks looks terrible in Safari on Mac. On iOS it is OK, chrome and firefox also OK. Does someone use Safari on Mac or people are using Chrome rather?

Comment: Do you know how to make the scrollbar be placed above the data and not disappear after the scrollable field is unfocused / unhovered?

Comment: not supported since chrome 114 https://caniuse.com/?search=overlay

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this..

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j7DmP/3/)**

Code used -

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height:10px;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: grey;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: As you can see in [usage of component](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6QwWVutfGaEZTl3bXBmUFF2UjA/edit) I have content in all 3 columns of second row, so I can't scroll just with middle column.

Comment: You want scrollbar for column 2 and all rows. am i right ?

Comment: I need to scroll with second column and second row. Second column scrolling I have implemented with javascript, but second row (whole row, not just some columns) scrolling I need to do natively.